# SettingWithCopyWarning even when using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value

Tags: python, pandas

This is one of the lines in my code where I get the `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
value1['Total Population']=value1['Total Population'].replace(to_replace='*', value=4)
```

Which I then changed to :

```
row_index= value1['Total Population']=='*'
value1.loc[row_index,'Total Population'] = 4
```

This still gives the same warning. How do I get rid of it?

Also, I get the same warning for a **convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)** function that I've used, is there any way to avoid that.

```
 value1['Total Population'] = value1['Total Population'].astype(str).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

**This is the warning message that I get:**

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Comment: Because your are updating the same set of values in that dataframe at the same time, you can try to use a temp variable to hold the result and apply back to the column, see if this helps ridding of the warning message.

Comment: what version of python & pandas are you using?

Answer (score 47):

If you use `.loc[row, column]` and still get the same error, it's probably because of copying another dataframe. You have to use `.copy()`.

This is a step-by-step error reproduction:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
#   col1    col2
#0  1   3
#1  2   4
#2  3   5
#3  4   6
```

Creating a new column and updating its value:

```
df['new_column'] = None
df.loc[0, 'new_column'] = 100
df
#   col1    col2    new_column
#0  1   3   100
#1  2   4   None
#2  3   5   None
#3  4   6   None
```

No error I receive. But, let's create another dataframe given the previous one:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.col1>2]
new_df
#col1   col2    new_column
#2  3   5   None
#3  4   6   None
```

Now, using `.loc`, I will try to replace some values in the same manner:

```
new_df.loc[2, 'new_column'] = 100
```

However, I got this hateful warning again:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

**SOLUTION**

use `.copy()` while creating the new dataframe will solve the warning:

```
new_df_copy = df.loc[df.col1>2].copy()
new_df_copy.loc[2, 'new_column'] = 100
```

Now, you won't receive any warnings!

If your dataframe is created using a filter on top of another dataframe, always use `.copy()`.

Comment: I'm getting this warning suddenly when I'm simply trying to add a new column using values from a list comprehension.  I'm using .loc.  There is no copy of a dataframe at play here.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: @Rexovas You need to trace it back, and maybe in many lines beforehand, you had a copy of the dataframe somewhere...

Comment: I was passing a sliced view of the dataframe to a function, which was then adding the new columns and saving the result as a CSV.  Everywhere in the code I was using `.loc` so I'm not sure why the warning, but adding `df = df.copy()` in that final function fixed it.  Still don't quite understand why it considered it a copy.

Comment: @Rexovas As I said, it has problem with sliced views of dataframe. Whenever you filter a dataframe, do not forget adding `.copy()`.

Comment: But using `.loc` should be sufficient as it guarantees the original dataframe is modified.  If I add new columns to the slice, I would simply expect the original df to have null/nan values for the rows that did not exist in the slice.  That’s the part I don’t understand.  It happens to be that in this case it doesn’t matter if the original df is modified or not, but I’m still not sure why copy is necessary.

Comment: That's only a warning. For instance, my expectation is that slice should be completely separated from the original one! In that case, `.copy()` helps me give the slice independence.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried setting directly?:

```
value1.loc[value1['Total Population'] == '*', 'Total Population'] = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how bad the data storage/memory implications are with this but it fixes it every time for your average dataframe:

```
def addCrazyColFunc(df):
    dfNew = df.copy()
    dfNew['newCol'] = 'crazy'
    return dfNew
```

Just like the message says... make a copy and you're good to go.  Please if someone can fix the above without the copy, please comment.  All the above loc stuff doesn't work for this case.

Answer (score 3):

I came here because I wanted to conditionally set the value of a new column based on the value in another column.

What worked for me was numpy.where:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...

df['Size'] = np.where((df.value > 10), "Greater than 10", df.value)
```

From [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), this is equivelant to:

```
[xv if c else yv
 for c, xv, yv in zip(condition, x, y)]
```

Which is a pretty nice use of zip...

Answer (score 2):

It is a warning about whether or not the source df is updated in replica update using sliced index.
If replica update, then try adding `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment',  None)`  before the line where the warning is raised

```py
df_value = pd.DataFrame({ 'Total Population':['a','b','c','*'] })
value1 = df_value[ df_value['Total Population']=='*']

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment',  None) # <=== SettingWithCopyWarning Off

row_index = value1['Total Population']=='*'
value1.loc[row_index,'Total Population'] = 44

pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment',  'warn') # <=== SettingWithCopyWarning Default
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to avoid the same warning message with syntax like this:

```
value1.loc[:, 'Total Population'].replace('*', 4)
```

Note that the dataframe doesn't need to be re-assigned to itself, i.e. <strike>value1['Total Population']=value1['Total Population']...</strike>

Comment: That looked sooo plausible to me.. but didn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

I created a new DataFrame and stored the value of only the columns that I needed to work on, it gives me no errors now!

Strange, but worked.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying it is a copy worked for me. I just added `.copy()` at the end of the statement

```
value1['Total Population'] = value1['Total Population'].replace(to_replace='*', value=4).copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem :

```
value1[:, 'Total Population'] = value1[:, 'Total Population'].replace(to_replace='*', value=4)
```